# Jfrog artifactory download an entire repo

Tags: curl, artifactory

I have been trying to download an entire repo in the Jfrog artifactory using curl as below but don't see an error nor the file downloaded. Is there any better way to download the entire repo from the artifactory service ?

```
curl -u user:pwd -X GET http://artifactory/local-repo/path/to/folder?archiveType=zip
```

Comment: You must first enable the full directory download in the JFrog settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired behavior using the `dl` command of the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI), for example:

Download all artifacts located under the all-my-frogs directory in the my-local-repo repository to the all-my-frogs folder under the current directory.

```
$ jf rt dl my-local-repo/all-my-frogs/ all-my-frogs/
```

Comment: I'm looking to do it via curl or wget as I can't install jfrog cli, any reason it should be blocked via curl or wget ?

Comment: @Avi you don't have to install the JFrog CLI. You can download it using `curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io/v2-jf | sh` and run the executable locally with `./jf`

Comment: I did try jf RT DL but error logs says file not found errors even though the folder and files exist